# incremental scan: Scan only the data which is not processed?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table AB which is updated as on 20191206 and the same table updated as on 20191209. I am working on another table CD where i need to scan AB and load into CD. So, i scanned AB on 20191206, it retrieved 2 records and loaded into CD. If i scan on 20191209, then i should scan only the data which is not scanned earlier, means i need to scan from timestamp: 20191207 in AB and load the remaining 3 records (20191207,20191208,20191209) into CD table. I would like to know how to do incremental scanning on a table? Here the platform is snowflake

```
    \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    ID & NAME & TIMESTAMP \\
    24 & mike & 20191205  \\
    36 & john & 20191206 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
ID & NAME & TIMESTAMP \\
24 & mike & 20191205  \\
36 & john & 20191206  \\
40 & nick & 20191207  \\
42 & bob  & 20191208  \\
43 & tia  & 20191209 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why have you also tagged SQL Server and SQLLite then?

Comment: While you are editing I is always capitalised in English

Comment: where timestamp > '20191206'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not in` for this.

Something along these lines, though I have not confirmed the syntax.

```
INSERT INTO CD A (SELECT * FROM AB B WHERE A.ID NOT IN B.ID);
```